# BackboneJS on Rails Syntax Error, unrecognized expression: /1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, syntax, backbone.js

I am trying to set up a show page for a Post that is accessed via a link:

```
<a class="post-link button" href="#">details</a>
```

When the post item is rendered, it is given an href like so:

```
this.$('a').attr('href', this.postUrl());

...

postUrl: function() {
  return "#posts/" + this.model.get('id');
}
```

When the fields are rendered, the links show up as:

```
http://[path_to_app]/#posts/[whatever_id]
```

When I click the link, then it *should* hit this router:

```
routes: {
  ''          : 'index',
  'new'       : 'newPost',
  "posts/:id" : 'show'
}
```

But I get this error, and it never goes in to the show function at all:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /1 jquery.js:4268
  Sizzle.errorjquery.js:4268
  Sizzle.filterjquery.js:4254
  Sizzlejquery.js:4044
  Sizzlejquery.js:5176
  jQuery.fn.extend.findjquery.js:5432
  jQuery.fn.jQuery.initjquery.js:188
  jQueryjquery.js:28
  hashchangetabs.js:9
  jQuery.event.dispatchjquery.js:3333
  jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

When I change the link to be "#post/" + id and the route to "post/:id", then this error does not occur.

I am in the process of learning Backbone, and could really use a hand here. Also of note: my routes root to posts#index action.

EDIT (more relevant code):

```
# Model
[APP].Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/posts'
});

#Router
[APP].Routers.Posts = Support.SwappingRouter.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.el = $('#posts');
    this.collection = options.collection;
  },

  routes: {
    ''          : 'index',
    'new'       : 'newPost',
    "posts/:id" : 'show'
  },

  index: function() {
    var view = new [APP].Views.PostsIndex({ collection: this.collection });
    this.swap(view);
  },

  newPost: function() {
    var view = new [APP].Views.PostsNew({ collection: this.collection });
    this.swap(view);
  },

  show: function(postId) {
    var post = this.collection.get(postId);
    var postsRouter = this;
    post.fetch({
      success: function() {
        var view = new [APP].Views.PostShow({ model: post });
        postsRouter.swap(view);
      }
    });
  }
});

#Post Item View
[APP].Views.PostItem = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
  },

  render: function () {
    this.$el.attr('id', 'post_' + this.model.id);
    this.$el.html(JST['posts/item']({ post: this.model }));
    this.renderFormContents();
    return this;
  },

  renderFormContents: function() {
    ...
    this.$('a').attr('href', this.postUrl());
  },

  postUrl: function() {
    return "#posts/" + this.model.get('id');
  }
});
```

Comment: is the post a backbone model?

Comment: Yes it is. And it has a url root to "/posts"

Comment: It’s pretty confusing that changing it to `post` instead of `posts` makes the error go away. Might there be other relevant code you’re neglecting to share with us? What happens if you manually visit `#posts/1` rather than clicking a link; is the router method called?

Comment: Going straight to the url renders the same issue. I'll put some more code up top. Thank you for looking

Comment: when you change it from #posts to #post the error doesn't occur, but is the data posted?

Comment: It gives me a 200 response, but with a lot of Response Text.

Comment: Does the `id` happen to be `1`? The error message suggests that something somewhere is trying to use a route as a jQuery selector (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4PymC/). What sort of things does `Support.SwappingRouter` get up to?

Comment: Yes, the id is 1. It throws /[:id] in the error, depending on what item click on. https://github.com/thoughtbot/backbone-support

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.net so that we can watch it happen? Something is feeding `'/:id'` to jQuery as a selector but I don't see what would be doing that.

Comment: Oh this is interesting... When I have "posts/#:id" : 'show' and I set my href to return "#posts/#" + this.model.get('id'), it all works...

Comment: Does it have to be `#:id` or would `posts/x:id` or `posts/%:id` work?

Comment: Only the #:id works. Everything else gives me the "Unrecognized expression /%[:id] or /x[:id]. Is that because it's telling the browser to ignore what comes after it? Or I suppose that's just hashbangs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere, someway, somehow, this issue was being caused by files not being loaded in a certain order. I wish I could be more specific, but I was not loading in backbone.min.js in the right place.

I was able to have some functionality, though, because I had included an old backbone partial file that I tried to customize, broken, and thought was deleted.

Really, really stupid mistake that I could not figure out for a little while. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

checkout url and urlRoot on the Backbone documentation: you probably dont need to be manually setting the url for a standard restful resource : http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url

Comment: I don’t believe this is relevant. There’s no server-side interaction happening here, right? It’s all in-browser, it’s a problem with the router.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the backbone support router? Or am I just doing it wrong...

Comment: oh @BuckDoyle answered before the post edit. you have to call the navigate function on the router. I'll edit my answer when i get a chance.

Comment: Why/where do I have to call that .navigate, exactly? When I do this in the routes: "posts:id" : 'show', the thing works like a charm. As soon as the slash is added, though, it blows up. So I suppose the people up top with the jQuery selector theory are on to something?